# Problems with side-by-side left and right div to center div

Tags: css

I'm having problems place the right and the left div side-by-side with the center div

something like that:

[image]

i want to push the right and the left div...

here is the css code:

```
//LEFT DIV
 .sidebar{
     float: left;
     width: 150px;    
  }

.sidebar li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


 //CENTER DIV
.texto{ 
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:700px;
}

 //RIGHT DIV
.Localizacao{
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
}
```

Thanks
Mark!

Comment: Could you please put some html so we can see how it is structured Mark, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want.if this is not the case tell me.you have only to replace your images and check whether it fits your needs.just copy & paste the code and try it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>working with bootstrap offline</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

<style type="text/css">
  body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: pink;
  }

.maincontainer{
  width: 100%;
  height:600px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

.left{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  border:1px solid orange;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 225px;

}

.middle{
  width: 450px;
  height: 550px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 425px;
}

.right{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  border:1px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  right: 202px;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="left">
    <h3>Proto</h3>
    <p>1. one</p>
    <p>2. two</p>
    <p>3. three</p>
    <p>4. four</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
   <img src="" style="width:100%;height:80%;box-shadow:1px 2px 1px black;">
   <p style="width:100%;height:20%;">your description here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  </div>
 </div>



</body>



</html>
```

Comment: worked for me thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the side, center and right divs are siblings, add `float:left` to all of them, also make sure your `boxing-size` is set to `border-box`, so that your divs are properly sized, since height and width sets the inner size of the box, then the border is added onto that, where as setting border-box lets you use width and height for exact over all dimensions.